# Connecting using WiFi Protected Setup in OS X

Tags: wifi

I have a MacBook Pro, and in OS X (running Lion), I can't figure out how to connect using the WiFi Protected Setup  feature of my router.

When I boot into Windows (Windows 7), using Boot Camp, I have to simply press the WPS button on the router while connecting.

Does OS X even support WPS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OS X doesn't support WPS. You'll have to manually enter the key. To do this, select your wifi network from the drop-down in the menu bar:

[image: wifi selector]

Then when prompted type in the wifi password:

[image]

If you don't know your password, you typically get it from your router's web interface (either via another computer, or connect your MacBook Pro via ethernet). To get there, enter `http://192.168.0.1` or `http://192.168.1.1` in your browser.

Comment: How do you suggest I enter this Wi-Fi password? NG/[8=A>I':QI:eSC)0|hy|wv)Y0z*I%.wMhrBbMzFq5|~8/H9!-~\3,^JAQ+Wa

Comment: Quite often, the default address for routers' web interfaces is `http://10.0.0.1` now, as with Comcast/Xfinity routers from Arris.

Comment: it's almost blasphemous to say "Quite often (...)", then referring to _one_ brand of routers.

Comment: @irrationalJohn Copy + Paste :)

Comment: "could not be joined" is not the same as prompting for a wifi password.  How do you get that prompt?

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't supported (Note: Printers are via airport, further information below about why it isn't supported for other devices.).

Please **don't use WPS** though, **it's not secure**. [More Information](https://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf)

@irrantion John, you can't have a long "random password" and expect it to be easy to enter whilst keeping it secure.

You could just copy and paste from a document (via usb) or printed document.

Maybe try something 20 characters long, or just accept its going to take forever to enter the password in. Remember keychain can sync your passwords for you.

Sure you can enable WPS on your router but then why have a complex password at all. **A 64 character password becomes a 7** (4+3) **character (ONLY 11,000 POSSIBILITIES!!) password.**